# Cloning github project in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to clone a project from github.

I first did git clone https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-frontend
and than i ran npm install and after that i did npm run.

But when the project opens in my browser I got this error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/index.js
SyntaxError: /home/ether/Documents/pancakeclone/pancake-frontend/src/index.js: Unexpected token (7:38)

   5 | var App_1 = require("./App");
   6 | var Providers_1 = require("./Providers");
>  7 | react_dom_1["default"].render(<react_1["default"].StrictMode>
     |                                       ^
   8 |     <Providers_1["default"]>
   9 |       <App_1["default"] />
  10 |     </Providers_1["default"]>
```

I did a google search but nothing helpful came up
So maybe someone on here can exyplain me what im doing wrong.

In my terminal I also got this error:

Could not open index.js in the editor.

```
To set up the editor integration, add something like REACT_EDITOR=atom to the .env.local file in your project folder and restart the development server. Learn more:
```

The problem is, i dont have a .env.local file in my project

Comment: maybe try re-installing node.js to discard that it's the environment problem

Answer (score 1):

On [contributing guideline](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-frontend/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md) it's written that you have to:

- Create a .env.development.local file at the root of the project. Add the following lines inside :

  ```
  REACT_APP_CROWDIN_APIKEY = ""
  REACT_APP_CROWDIN_PROJECTID = ""
  ```

You'll need this in order to get the i18n system to work. Contact a dev if you need these values.

- Install the dependencies

  ```
  yarn
  yarn start
  ```

Note: If you don't have `yarn`, run `npm install -g yarn`.

I tried here locally and it works:

[image]

Comment: did you get any errors after running it for a while

Comment: i did all the steps, from creating a file to using yarn but after the page loads it keeps crashing

Comment: and i get those errors: Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid address (argument="address", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.0.10) (argument="owner", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)

Comment: Yes I didn't see before but after a while it fails... looking into console seems that there is a problem with translations but I don't know why....